# concavity of $\log [ (1+\frac{x_0}{1+x_0+x_1/2+x_2/4}) (1+\frac{x_1}{1+x_0/4+x_1+x_2/2}) (1+\frac{x_2}{1+x_0/2+x_1/4+x_2}) ]$

Tags: convexity, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f:~ [0,1]^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be

$$
f(x_0,x_1,x_2)= \log \left[ \left(1+\frac{x_0}{1+x_0+\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{4}}\right) \left(1+\frac{x_1}{1+x_1+\frac{x_2}{2}+\frac{x_0}{4}}\right) \left(1+\frac{x_2}{1+x_2+\frac{x_0}{2}+\frac{x_1}{4}}\right) \right].
$$

My guess is that $f$ is a concave function. The standard approach to prove multivariate concavity is to find the Hessian matrix and prove that it is non-positive definite. However, it seems to be an overwhelming approach for this function. Can we somehow use the structure of $f$ to prove or disprove the concavity?

**Edit1:**
The general form is $f:~ [0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})= \log \left[ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{x_k}{1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}q^jx_{(k+j)~\text{mod}~n}}\right) \right], 0<q<1.
$$

**Edit2:**
I changed the notation and started the indices from zero to make the general case accurate.

Comment: Did you write down the minors of Hessian matrix? It may be ugly, but working.

Comment: And this raises of course some curiosity: does it still hold more generally upon replacing $\frac12$ and $\frac14$ respectively by $q$ and $q^2$ (for any $0<q<1$)?

Comment: And likewise for $n$ variables, $\log\prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{x_k}{ 1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} q^jx_{k+j}})$ with indexes cyclically mod $n$.

Comment: Interestingly, looking at is as f(x) = f1(x) + f2(x) + f3(x), then f1(x), f2(x), f3(x) are not concave individually, but their sum is, so they all combine perfectly to produce concavity

Comment: Should be $\log\prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{x_k}{ 1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} q^jx_{k+j}})$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I'm trying to calculate them but it seems to be ugly. Furthermore, I am more interested in the general case that Wolfgang mentioned. For that one, there are $n$ variables and the minors seem to be ugly. Besides, for the general case, currently I don't know what to do with the minors after calculating them.

Comment: @Wolfgang: You brought up a very interesting generalized form. Thank you. Actually I am more interested in this generalized form. I just wrote the special case up there in my question for simplicity.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: You're exactly right. The individual functions are not concave but I guess they add up to a concave function.

Comment: Bonus points to whoever can figure out how (I'm not saying it can be done) to model f(x) using a combination of exponential and (rotated) quadratic cones, thereby allowing it to be entered and used in CVX.  This would also prove concavity for general n. See, for example, sections 5.1 and 5.2 of MOSEK Modeling Cookbook https://docs.mosek.com/MOSEKModelingCookbook-letter.pdf .

Comment: @Mark L. Stone: Looking in the link, I find nothing to  prove the general case. Can you base your statements?

Comment: @James: Two dozen minutes ago you changed the  notations ($x_0,\,x_1,\,x_2$ instead of $x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3$), not indicating it. This is a bad practice.

Comment: @user64494: Sorry you are right. I did that because the general case was not accurate in the previous version. But I forgot to mention it. I just explained it in the question.

Comment: @user64494 The link doesn't provide a solution but sections 5.2.x show solutions for some simpler cases. So something clever would need to be done, if it can be done at all. But individual additive log terms not being concave suggests it is difficult, at best, to do. Also, with large enough x (larger than 1), it is possible to get indefinite Hessian; so if I didn't make a mistake on that, the function is not concave on its entire "natural" domain, which further suggests the impossibility or difficulty of producing a convex conic formulation.

Comment: @Wolfgang: I think I also need to use a modulo function in the denominator for the indices in the general form as I did above in Edit 1.

Comment: Yes you do definitely. It applies to all indices.

Answer (score 6):

Maple 2018 does it by

```
restart; 
 A := log((1+x[1]/(1+x[1]+(1/2)*x[2]+(1/4)*x[3]))*(1+x[2]/(1+x[2]+
(1/2)*x[3]+(1/4)*x[1]))*(1+x[3]/(1+x[3]+(1/2)*x[2]+(1/4)*x[3]))):
H := VectorCalculus:-Hessian(A, [x[1], x[2], x[3]]):
LinearAlgebra:-IsDefinite(H, query = 'negative_semidefinite')
assuming x[1]>=0,x[1]<=1,x[2]>=0,x[2]<=1,x[3]>=0,x[3]<=1;
```

> true

Addition. Maple cracks the Wolfgang's modification too, but only for concrete values of $n$:

```
restart; n := 25: xx := [seq(x[j], j = 1 .. n)]:
A := log(mul(1+x[k]/(1+add(q^j*x[k+j], j = 0 .. n-1)), k = 1 .. n)):
H := VectorCalculus:-Hessian(A, xx):
LinearAlgebra:-IsDefinite(H, query = 'negative_semidefinite')
assuming seq(x[s]>=0,s=1..n),seq(x[s]<=1,s=1..n),q>0,q<1
```

> true

Comment: Could you define the new general form with modulo function in Maple?